# Proving convergence by proving a sequence is uniformly Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis

So the problem is as follows:

Prove that if {a<sub>k</sub>} is a bounded sequence of numbers and a sequence {s<sub>n</sub>} is defined on (-1,1) by
$$s_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k ,$$
then {s<sub>n</sub>} converges to a continuous function on (-1,1). Hint: Prove this sequence is uniformly Cauchy on each interval [-r, r] for 0 < r < 1.

I attempted to use the definition of uniformly Cauchy by saying n > m and M=sup{a<sub>k</sub>}:
$$|\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k-\sum_{k=0}^ma_kx^k|=|\sum_{k=m+1}^na_kx^k|\le|\sum_{k=m+1}^nMx^k|\le(n-m)M\le nM$$
However, I couldn't figure out how to choose my N such that n,m $\gt$ N implied
$$|s_n(x)-s_m(x)|\lt\epsilon$$
for every $\epsilon$ $\gt$ 0. Am I making an incorrect assumption of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can get a better upper bound that you currently have.  In particular:
$$
\left| 
\sum_{k=m+1}^n a_k x^k
\right| \leq 
\sum_{k=m+1}^n M |x|^k \leq 
M \sum_{k=m+1}^\infty r^k \leq \frac{M}{1-r}r^{m+1}
$$
*(in fact, the sequence is **not** uniformly Cauchy on $(-1,1)$, so we need to use that $r$ in some capacity)*

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the Weierstrass M test. If $|x|\le r < 1,$ we have  $|a_nx^n| \le Mr^n.$ Since $\sum Mr^n <\infty,$ we have the desired uniform convergence on $[-r,r]$ by Weierstrass.